# add multiple columns for each value

Tags: mysql, r, multiple-columns

I have a question concerning R-Studio.

I wrote the following query:

```
var1 <- dbGetQuery(con, 'select sum(table1.amount) as x,
      mid(table3.date,6,2) as month from table2, table3, table1 where
      table3.id = table1.bnr and table1.tnr = table2.tnr and
      table1.tnr = "123" and mid(table3.date,1,4) = "2016"
      group by month order by month ASC')
```

it puts out a table with two attributes (a and month).

How can I edit the table so that it includes values for all table.tnr (not only "123") without adding each column manually?

Thank you!

Comment: Please can you send screen shots of a and month so I can analyze? Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: Please don't send screen shots.  Use `dput()` to give R code that can produce them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

dput(var1):

structure(list(x = c(50, 53, 87, 65, 91, 59, 77, 110, 117, 
127, 146, 107), month = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
"07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12")), .Names = c("x", "month"
), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")

Not sure if this is what you asked me to do.